# Different Events for mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I want to have when a user clicks a login icon on desktop it would have a modal dialog show up. However on smaller devices like mobile and tablets, I want a reactjs route to kick in and show in my "main" content area and not use a modal dialog.

I am not sure how to do this cleanly, first I was thinking maybe there are 2 clicks, one for touch and one for click but what happens on ipad where it might be big enough to show a dialog and should go that way.

Next I was thinking of just having 2 separate icons and depending on my media query it shows the right one, though I just don't like the duplicate code.

Any other ways? I don't want to start writing size logic in my java script code as everything else is being handled in media queries right now.

Comment: If you already used mediaqueries, then you might want to try the 2 separate icons.

Comment: media queries are the right way to go.  Lots of ways to do this.

Comment: @DCR - could you go into the ways I can do this

Comment: sure, 1 way is to create two separate icons and then using media-queries  set the display to hidden or visible based on the screen size.  Do you know how to use media-queries?

Comment: I do know how they work, and hence why in my post I wrote "Next I was thinking of just having 2 separate icons and depending on my media query it shows the right one, though I just don't like the duplicate code."

Comment: You're doing two different things, not sure I see where the duplicate code comes in. But maybe I'm just parsing words. Since you are using reactjs, why not get the screen size and then render accordingly?

Comment: Well, I will be duplicating the same image twice, meaning I got to update 2 locations now if it ever changes. Second it is not only thing I will have to copy as I have text that is also clickable. So now it is a few lines I got to copy. If this is the best way I will do it but I do like to try to keep it keep duplicate stuff to minimal if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single icon.

You can use `matchMedia` - the javascript equivalent of CSS `@media` queries - to determine whether the browser viewport is larger or smaller and then add a class to the icon to record this.

When the icon is clicked:

- if it contains the `.larger-viewport` class, it will bring up the modal dialog
- if it contains the `.smaller-viewport` class, it will fire the reactjs.

```js
// Initialise Variables

var iconForModal;
var iconForReact;
var loginIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('login-icon')[0];

// Check and record viewport size

function checkViewportSize() {

    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)").matches) {

        loginIcon.className = 'login-icon larger-viewport';
    }

    else {

        loginIcon.className = 'login-icon smaller-viewport';
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', checkViewportSize, false);
window.addEventListener('load', checkViewportSize, false);


// Activate Login

function activateLogin() {

    if (loginIcon.classList.contains('larger-viewport')) {

        console.log('Login Modal Activated');

    }

    if (loginIcon.classList.contains('smaller-viewport')) {

        console.log('Login React Activated')
    }
}

loginIcon.addEventListener('click', activateLogin, false);
```

```html
<button type="button" class="login-icon">Login</button>
```

Comment: Hmm, yea I will have to think about this, if it is truly better then duplicating the code, the thing I don't like about this and maybe it really is not that big of a deal, is that now you have essentially 2 media queries to look after. As basically your css and now javascript number have to be in sync. Maybe it is not too much of a problem as it probably rarely changes.